# Is there a meaningful difference between 推量形＋と(も)/が and 過去形＋ところで?

Tags: grammar, nuances

I know that 過去形＋ところで is followed by a negative judgement, and 推量形＋と(も)/が can be either, but is there any other difference?

For example

> どんなに説明し**たところで**、わたしの気持ちはわかってもらえないだろう。
>
> どんなに説明し**ようと**、わたしの気持ちはわかってもらえないだろう。

or

> いくら謝っ**たところで**、彼女との関係は元には戻らないと思う。
>
> いくら謝**ろうと**、彼女との関係は元には戻らないと思う。

Answer (score 2):

In the context of *no matter how/what/...* or *even if*, I think both are the same. Some examples:

- どんなに金をもらったところでこれは売れない No matter how much I'm paid, I can't sell this.
- どんなに金をもらってもこれは売れない
- いくら説得したところで彼は会社を辞めるだろう No matter how much I try to dissuade him, he will leave the company.
- いくら説得しようとも彼は会社を辞めるだろう (説得しても may be more natural)

Without どんなに/いくら, these would mean "Even if I..." and still there will be no difference with ところで/(よ)うとも.

In other contexts, they mean something totally different. (Note it is usually ようと in this case.)

- 50ページまで説明したところでチャイムが鳴った **At the time when** I finished (up to) Page 50, there was a chime.
- 50ページまで説明しようと少し急いだ I paced up a little **in order to** finish up to Page 50.